# HttpUrlConnection - android app - oauth2 authorization with spring web service

Tags: java, android, spring, http, oauth-2.0

I try to connect with my spring rest service from android app. My code doesn't work. I learn from the following tutorial: 
http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/

and I try to do this point:

"Ask for tokens[access+refresh] using HTTP POST on /oauth/token, with grant_type=password,and resource owners credentials as req-params. Additionally, send client credentials in Authorization header.
POST http://localhost:8080/SpringSecurityOAuth2Example/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=bill&password=abc123"

I tried to do it in the other way, not like in the tutorial but using HttpURLConnection. How should look parameters to make appropriate request? 
I simulate it on my phone and it has the connection with local network by wifi.

```
try {
        String plainClientCredentials="my-trusted-client:secret";
        String base64ClientCredentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(plainClientCredentials.getBytes()));
        URL urlObj = new URL("http://192.168.1.150:8080/Web_Maxim_Manager/oauth/token");
        HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
        urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConn.setDoInput(true);
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("grant_type", "password");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("username", "bill");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("password", "abc123");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+base64ClientCredentials);
        urlConn.connect();
        String response = urlConn.getResponseMessage();
        userName.setText(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        userName.setText("uuuu");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


     W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:623)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:198)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:687)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:541)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1179)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:392)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:295)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
W/System.err:     at runwithme.android.maxim.com.myapplication.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
```

I tested service with postman apps and it works. So, the fault is in my android app.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Problem was in the faulty set application permissions. Additional thing is that:

```
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("grant_type", "password");
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("username", "bill");
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("password", "abc123");
```

should not be set as a request parameters, but they should be part of url.
Permissions should be set as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```